# Changing div to a different color, wait 3 seconds, before changing color back using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery code that is suppose to make a div blue, and then wait 3 seconds, before making it back to black. But it's just staying at its original color, black, and not changing to blue at all, before changing back to black. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id = "div" style="width:250px;height:250px; background-color:black;"></div>

$(function(){

$("#div").css({"background-color" : "blue"})
         .delay(3000)
         .css({"background-color" : "black"});

}) //end of $(function())
```

Here's a fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/5wjy9aqu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `animate()` and also include `jQueryUI` for animating colours.

```
$(function () {
    $("#div").animate({
        "background-color": "blue"
    }, 1000)
    .delay(3000)
    .animate({
        "background-color": "black"
    }, 1000);
});
```

**Fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/zydLvbuf/**

Well, if you don't wanna add the whole jQueryUI, you can also add a [custom plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) for just animating the colours.

```
$("#block").animate({
  backgroundColor: $.Color({ saturation: 0 })
}, 1500 );
```

Comment: Is there a link to include jQueryUI?

Comment: @jessica On the left.

Comment: There's no need to add whole jQuery UI to animate the `background-color` property. You can just use [jQuery.color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) as specified on the animation docs.

Comment: @MinusFour That's one more way. It is totally a different plugin. Lemme add that. Is that the reason for downvote?

Comment: @MinusFour Please check it out, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's because `delay` doesn't work like that.

You can always do it like this:

```
$('#div').css("background-color", "blue");
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#div').css("background-color", "black");
}, 3000);
```

You can also use, queue if you really insisit on `delay`.

```
$('div').css('background-color', 'blue').delay(3000).queue(function(){
     $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
     $(this).dequeue();
});
```

Which if you ask me, is not really a good option.

Comment: How does delay work then? According to w3school, delay() is suppose to delay however many milliseconds before executing the next query.

Comment: @jessica _Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of `.show()` or `.hide()` which do not use the effects queue._ Don't follow w3school, use jQuery API guide for reference https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: "Delay works by delaying the queue." Sounds exactly like what I was saying.

Comment: Well, `css` changes aren't queued up normally, they are done immediately. Only certain functions in jQuery are being queued up. Like for example, animations or animations helpers (such as `show`, `hide`, `fadeIn`)

Comment: On the topic of "queued up", what exactly does it mean? Does it mean to chain up a certain number of queries, so they be be executed in order?

Comment: Exactly. When you queue up things you put them at the end of your queue. `delay` actually queue up a delay, so if you queue up anything after the delay it will be executed after it.

Comment: How do I check if a queue is executed immediately or queued up to be executed one by one? For example, how would I check if prop() is executed immediately or not?

Comment: And btw, is there a way to FORCE it to not execute immediately. For example, can you force css to be queue up so it can be executed one by one?

Comment: @jessica, it's usually the jQuery effects. You can force it to be on the queue through the `$.queue`, which is what i used on my second example.

Answer (score 0):

In a modern browser you can also use the following CSS-only solution: http://fiddle.jshell.net/otzm74xk/.

CSS:

```
#div {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: blue;
    animation: blacken 0s linear 3s 1 forwards;
}

@keyframes blacken {
    100% {
        background-color: black;    
    }
}
```